# Has winforms events behavior changed in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms app that I'm writing to a file every other line to see what is happening.   I have a Click event that sets a value on the control.  What I've noticed on this one win 10 machine is that the After Value Changed event fires immediately and the code from it interrupts the  Click event.  On my win 7 machine it fires after the Click completes.  That has been my understanding of the way events work.  Has something changed? Is there control over this in the OS?  This is an infragistics control, so I don't know what is going on under the hood.  Maybe they are messing with my events.  Just wanted to rule out MS first.  We are on VS2008 and .net 3.5.  There are no "DoEvents" in my form, not sure what else could cause this.  Thanks.

Posting simplified code in case I'm not clear.

```
Private Sub umvCalendar_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles umvCalendar.MouseDown

         Logger.Write("Beginning umvCalendar_MouseDown ############")
         umvCalendar.CalendarInfo.ActiveDay = Today
         Logger.Write("ENDING umvCalendar_MouseDown")
    End Sub


Private Sub uciCalendarInfo_AfterActiveDayChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.AfterActiveDayChangedEventArgs) Handles uciCalendarInfo.AfterActiveDayChanged
       Logger.Write("uciCalendarInfo_AfterActiveDayChanged") 
    End Sub
```

The log from this machine looks like this.  I was expecting the last two lines to be swapped, as it is on other machines.

```
18:04:25:214 :  Beginning umvCalendar_MouseDown ############  
18:04:25:231 :  uciCalendarInfo_AfterActiveDayChanged  
18:04:25:240 :  ENDING umvCalendar_MouseDown
```

Comment: I'm sure it's Infragistic control causing this unexpected behavior. We have migrated to Windows 10 and our winform app is working without any complaints.

Comment: Post the code, or we can't really help.

Comment: VS2008, Net.3.5 and what version of Infragistics? They update their control regularly and it is totally possible that using an old version of these controls doesn't work well with Win10

Comment: infragistics 9.1.  Yes, it's really old, upgrade will be painful.  I'm pretty sure that's where the problem is, just hoping for an easier answer.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what the problem was, but after more questions it was discovered that this machine was a Dell Touchscreen laptop, disabling the touchscreen fixed it.  So I guess either a hardware or diver problem.  Combined with Infragistics, since only Infragistics controls had problems.